# Switch vs if ... else if ... else

Tags: c

I have a question. I'm studying for my exam and I don't know how to do answer this. Basically I have to change the instructions if...else if... else, to a instruction switch in order that the output of the program stays the same.

```
void main()
{
    int x;
    x = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; ++i) {
        if (i <= 3)
            do {
                x += i;
                if (x >= 4)
                    break;
            } while (i % 2 == 0);
        else if ((i > 3) && (i < 5))
            x += 2;
        else
            continue;
    }
    while (x > 0) {
        printf(" x=%d ", x);
        x -= 1;
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Am I allowed to do a switch inside of the for loop?

Comment: You know in C, we can do that `int x = 1;` ;)

Comment: What is the difference between else if ((i > 3) && (i < 5) and if ( x == 4 ) ?

Comment: @Stargateur I know that ofc, I just copy pasted from the exam.

Comment: @Michi I don't think there is one, just copied it from the exam paper. My teacher is outdated, he likes to complicate things

Comment: Yikes. Looks like a class in "how to not program in C".

Comment: @Lundin As an exam question, the weak code does have merit: This is code that is not how to program in C, but an assessment of how to improve it. Re-factoring and faithfully maintaining functionality of prior poorly written code is a challenging skill worthy of assessment. Many a new C programmer today will be obliged to improve exiting code bases - and not break them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course you can. A `for` loop controls the execution of a *statement* and a `switch` block *is* a statement.

Given that `i` is in the inclusive range of 1 to 9, you can replace the `if` block with

```
switch (i){
case 1: case 2: case 3:
    // that replaces 'if (i <= 3)'
    // ToDo - the code here
    break; // to obviate follow-through.
case 4:
    // that replaces 'if ((i > 3) && (i < 5))'
    // ToDo - the code here
    break;
default:
    // that replaces 'else'
    continue; // note that this is for the for loop, not the switch
}
```

Note that the behaviour of `if (x >= 4) break;` is **not** changed by this refactoring.

I'm not convinced however that replacing the `if` block with a `switch` is the right thing to do here: the boundaries `i <= 3` and `i >= 5` are less naturally handled with a `switch`; perhaps changing the type of `i` to `unsigned` and handling `case 0:` explicitly would alleviate this somewhat.

Comment: It would have been a truly evil question if in the OP `x += 2;` was instead a `break;`.

Comment: Yeah the output is the same, I did not change the behaviour of if (x>=4) break;

Comment: @StoryTeller: I was thinking exactly the same thing.

Comment: @GemTaylor: U wot? `continue` has no direct use in a `switch`.

Comment: You are right... you unlearn something every day. I had it in my mind that continue  was equivalent to break. Perhaps in a different language.

Comment: @GemTaylor: `continue` is the same as a `break` in PHP. Nice.

Comment: May be useful to note: the `continue` is for the `for()` loop and not the `switch`.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work

```
void main()
{
    int x;
    x = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; ++i) {
        switch (i) {
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
                 do {
                     x += i;
                     if (x >= 4)
                         break;
                 } while (i % 2 == 0);
                 break;
            case 4:
                 x += 2;
                 break;
            default:
                continue;
                break;
         }
    }
    while (x > 0) {
        printf(" x=%d ", x);
        x -= 1;
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Ha. Let's publish jointly! +1.

Comment: @Bathsheba ok +1 too!

Comment: Interesting use of `continue;
                break;`  `continue;` should be sufficient.  Even leaving the `default:` case out would not change functionality - but may look too different.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the switch statement inside the loops.

IMO the `switch` is more readable than the long `if else` sequences. Performance is almost the same.

Some compilers (gcc for example) have switch extensions making the range checks in the switch statements shorter.

```
switch(age)
{
    case 0 ... 12:
    printf("Child\n");
    break;
    case 13 ... 19:
    printf("Teenager\n");
    break;
    case 20 ... 200:
    printf("Adult\n");
    break;
    default:
    printf("Immortal\n");
    break;
}
```

It is not portable of course.

Comment: "Performance is almost the same." - what do you mean by this? That's a can of worms right there; I'd be inclined to drop that statement if I were you.

Comment: I mean that the long if sequences are often compiled to the lookup tables - very similar to the switch statements.

Comment: I'd never advise to use non-portable features, never ever.